# How do you link and use an external JS file and use it in ejs files?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to link a javascript file to an ejs file. It contains code for drawing a randomised canvas background.

I have this in my app file:

```
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + 'public/js'));
```

I have tried linking it like this in the ejs(html):

```
<script src="js/bg.js"></script>
```

And tried to use it's function init(no variables) like this:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="7735" height="4354" onload="init()"></canvas>
```

It works perfectly if i put the code into this:

```
<script> code... </script>
```

So my problem is probably linking incorrectly. I didn't get any errors in visual code or firefox :(
Can someone help me with linking an external js file?

Answer (score 0):

It was actually correct. The problem was that the onload was on the wrong element. Opps